# Adding frequency count to Concordance function in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashtable, word-frequency

Hoping to get input on whether my logic is correct or not.  My assignment is just to modify the function to keep track of word frequency.  I think I have added a counter to do this.

```
public void enterWord (Object word, Integer line) {
    Vector set = (Vector) dict.get(word);
    int counter = 0;
    if (set == null) {  // word not in dictionary
    set = new Vector( );
    dict.put(word, set);  // enter word and empty Vector
    } // if
    if (allowDupl || !set.contains(line)) {
    counter++;
    set.addElement(line);
    set.addElement(counter);
    }

} // enterWord
```

Original code
Sample input:

```
this is just a test or is it
is
just
a
test
```

output:

```
a: 1 4
this: 1
it: 1
is: 1 1 2
or: 1
just: 1 3
test: 1 5
```

With the counter I added the output looks like this:

```
a: 1 1 4 1
this: 1 1
it: 1 1
is: 1 1 1 1 2 1
or: 1 1
just: 1 1 3 1
test: 1 1 5 1
```

Comment: `Vector` class already have a `size()` method that return number of elements in it.

Comment: why are you using `set` here?

Comment: Your code seems to do unnecessary things. What is the `Integer line` parameter for, why do you even need it? Why don't you just use a `HashMap<Object, Integer>` (or `HashMap<String, Integer>`) to keep track of the word count?

Comment: I am modifying given code.  There are a total of four files given.  I am just supposed to modify the code to give the frequency of the words.  Before modification the code already will accept an input file of text, and output the words found and the line numbers they are found on.  With that counter there it seems kind of redundant.

Comment: I am not sure why the code was written the way it was written, but if you need to see more of the code just let me know.  I just figured that this function was probably the only place I needed to modify, but I might have to also create a new function and modify the layout of the output a little as well.  This is what I have to come to understand as I have been working on this.  I have not coded in Java in years, and did not even know how to compile and run this when I first posted.  But I have gotten that much figured out now...